# python multiple execute command

Tags: python, powershell, vmware, powercli

```
import subprocess

command = r'C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1\""'
command2 = 'Get-PoolEntitlement -pool_id gameserver2 | Remove-
PoolEntitlement'
output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
output = subprocess.getoutput(command2)
print(output)
```

I have run multiple commands that related commands. But I dont

error:

```
'Get-PoolEntitlement' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute multiple cmd commands at once, you can put '&&' between them.

For example `cd documents&&start` would both navigate to the documents folder and start a new command prompt, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your first command you are invoking PowerShell:

```
command = r'C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1\""'
```

In the second you are not!

```
command2 = 'Get-PoolEntitlement -pool_id gameserver2 | Remove-PoolEntitlement'
```

So you should just need to correct that like:

```
command2 = r'C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "Get-PoolEntitlement -pool_id gameserver2 | Remove-PoolEntitlement"'
```